# Numpy can't exist on the same system as Unreal Engine - aptitude?

Tags: 16.04, dependencies, aptitude, clang

I'm having an exceedingly difficult time resolving dependencies for Unreal Engine on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I'm now being presented with a dilemia which appears to require me to either remove numpy or give up my installation for Unreal Engine. Can someone please explain how I can potentially resolve this issue as I will be using both. Here is the log from aptitude when I'm installing a dependency for clang-3.8 known as libblang1-3.8. **In short, clang-3.8 and its dependencies are the issue**:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libclang1-3.8 libobjc-5-dev{ab} libobjc4{ab} 
0 packages upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,624 kB of archives. After unpacking 18.4 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libobjc4 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is installed.
 libobjc-5-dev : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is installed.
                 Depends: libgcc-5-dev (= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libclang1-3.8 [Not Installed]                      
2)     libobjc-5-dev [Not Installed]                      
3)     libobjc4 [Not Installed]                           



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Remove the following packages:                                              
1)      libgfortran3                                                              
2)      liblapack3                                                                
3)      python-numpy                                                              

      Downgrade the following packages:                                           
4)      cpp-5 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]          
5)      g++-5 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]          
6)      gcc-5 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]          
7)      gcc-5-base [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]     
8)      gcc-5-base:i386 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]
9)      libasan2 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]       
10)     libatomic1 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]     
11)     libcc1-0 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]       
12)     libcilkrts5 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]    
13)     libgcc-5-dev [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]   
14)     libgomp1 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]       
15)     libitm1 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]        
16)     liblsan0 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]       
17)     libmpx0 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]        
18)     libquadmath0 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]   
19)     libstdc++-5-dev [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]
20)     libstdc++6 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]     
21)     libstdc++6:i386 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]
22)     libtsan0 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]       
23)     libubsan0 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]      

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                                
24)     inkscape recommends python-numpy                                          


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] q
Abandoning all efforts to resolve these dependencies.
Abort.
```